# Extracting second level menu from JSON

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-7

I use JSON in my Laravel application as mentioned below. I'm trying to retrieve the children sub-level menu from the JSON but it doesn't work.

```
[
   {
      "pages":"Home",
      "href":""
   },
   {
      "pages":"About",
      "href":"about"
   },
   {
      "pages":"Contact",
      "href":"contact",
      "children":[
         {
            "pages":"Profile",
            "href":"profile"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Can somebody help me out with this?

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly. Add what you've tried and explain what _"doesn't work"_ means in your case. What happens? Errors? Wrong data? Server crash?

Comment: If you're trying to output the menu in a navbar, please provide the code of your foreach loop and the navbar structure so we can find where the problem is

Comment: @HassanAzzam here is the blade template code
``
@foreach($m as $m1)
                                <li>
                                    <?php $url = $m1->href; ?>
                                    <a href="{{url($url)}}"><span class="dropdown__trigger header-active"><?php echo $m1->pages?></span></a>
                                </li>   
                                
                            @endforeach

Till now, the above code is working but im unable to retrieve the children from the code.

Comment: Ok i will post an answer now on how to iterate through your menu items

Answer (score 1):

Inside the `@foreach` loop you will need to check if the current menu item has `children` and if it does, then you add a second loop to iterate through the `children`.

So it would look like this:

```
 @foreach($m as $page) 
    <li> 
        <a href="{{ url($page->href) }}">
            {{ $page->pages }}
            @if(property_exists($page, 'children'))
                <span class="dropdown__trigger header-active">▼</span>
            @endif
        </a>

        @if(property_exists($page, 'children'))
            <ul class="submenu">
                @foreach($page->children as $subPage) 
                    <li> 
                        <a href="{{ url($subPage->href) }}">{{ $subPage->pages }}</a>
                    </li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        @endif
    </li>
 @endforeach
```

Comment: Well i just modified the answer, please check again with the new code.

Comment: i used `@if` instead of `@isset`